# How to find exact error line in laravel 5.4 blade?

Tags: php, debugging, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I know laravel caches blade files, and when there is an error in blade, in version  5.3 error would be something like this :

```
Undefined offset: 0 (View:b5c0ef4df49585eadd7fc1fa15b2d8a03e8c3bdd.php) line: 47
```

Then I can go to cached files and find the exact line,

But in version 5.4 laravel reference the exact blade file(not cached file) but without a line number!  Something like this :

```
Undefined offset: 0 (View: C:\wamp64\www\project\resources\views\events\partial\event_details_members.blade.php)
in Collection.php (line 1537)
```

Now how to find the error?

**UPDATE**

I know where the problem is, and how to fix that, But I want Laravel to tell me this automatically whether I have to look for it manually.  what if the blade file is very big?

Comment: can you delete cache files from storage\framework\views and check or you can run php artisan clear

Comment: Show the code part where you think the error is?

Comment: @iCoders  then laravel cache them again

Comment: @MayankPandeyz  , here it is :  `<div>{{  $m->translations[0]->role }} </div>`, I khow this is exactly the error

Comment: ca you share full code of the blade.i guess this is because 0 key not there in that data

Comment: @iCoders Yes I know that, and I can fix that, I want laravel to tell me this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Laravel 5.7, the output shows stack frames on the left side and details of selected frame on right side. If you cruise through the stack, you'll find that one of the entries in there is the parsed version of your blade file (normally located near the `(main)` frame towards the bottom of the stack). Clicking this frame will take you to the exact line of the blade file that resulted in that exception.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

its not an easy way to find the error which raised in a **cached view file**.

but if your **debug mode** is *off* and you are going to find it out very quick,

I suggest this following steps:

I know this is not tidy.

1- find error in `./storage/laravel/log/today.log` :

for example:

```
(b5c0ef4df49585eadd7fc1fa15b2d8a03e8c3bdd.php) (line : 47)
```

2- output the files content usng `cat` :

```
cat ./storage/framework/view/b5c0ef4df49585eadd7fc1fa15b2d8a03e8c3bdd.php
```

(file name from error log)

3- copy the content from terminal to an editor (from first line to the end)

4- you can find the buggy line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Laravel Debugbar`. This is easy to use. Follow below link you will get what you want.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I have debugbar, It give's me the exact exception that laravel does, nothing more

Comment: So what you want then?

Comment: Laravel exception or debugbar does not give me error line, See my update